# How to return HTML object on server side processing for dataTable jQuery?

Tags: jquery, datatables

My point is... i have a dataTable with over 20k records, so i'm server side processing it, so the user browser stays sharp.

But, i have buttons i must 'assembly' to edit, remove or activate some records, and when i try to put html on the return of the server side processing, i get an error from dataTable, even if my json is well formatted...

so, what can i do?

I've tried using fnDrawCallback, but it runs after the data placement on the table.

Thanks in advance, Jorge Ferrari.

Comment: What is the error you receive from dataTable?

Comment: If you want to run callback before data placement, try `fnPreDrawCallback`

Comment: preDraw din't work as well :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can build html controls using [mRender](http://datatables.net/ref#mRender) in your column definitions.
I have used this to create edit links on each datatable row using a value returned by the json data as a dynamic parameter:

```
    'aoColumns': [
                 {
                  'mRender': function (data, type, row) {
                           var EditLinkText = ' |<a href=\'Edit/' + row[10] + '\'>Edit</a>';
                           return EditLinkText;
                  }
             }
           ]
```

Answer (score 1):

I just find out how i may do it.

i can use the fnServerData.. here's an example

```
// POST data to server
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#example').dataTable( {
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "xhr.php",
    "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings ) {
       oSettings.jqXHR = $.ajax( {
    "dataType": 'json',
    "type": "POST",
    "url": sSource,
    "data": aoData,
    "success": fnCallback
      } );
    }
  } );
} );
```